# Consultar base de datos en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

estoy empezando en Flutter, y tengo una duda no  se si me puedan ayudar, esta es mi funcion que tiene los datos almacenados en la base de datos Sqlite

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en mi page de home tengo un menu de HiddenDrawer quiero traer la lista de la consulta aca pero no lo he logrado no se si me puedan guiar gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `initState` no puede ser `async` , crea un método aparte `async` y llámalo desde el `initState`.

```dart
Future<void> tuMetodoAsincrono() async {
  //tu lógica aquí, que no requiera context ni interacción con UI
}

void initState(){
  tuMetodoAsincrono();
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: gracias lo estoy solucionado me podrias ayudar ya lo puse en un metodo y lo estoy llamando en el iniState();  en el metodo que cree estoy retornando un array que si lo tengo guardao mira pero si hago un print() me sale el texto Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' y quiero acceder al primer valor del array lo tengo asi no se si me puedas aclarar gracias   consulta() async {
    List<Opciones> listOpciones = await DatabaseHelper.instance.verOpciones();
    //Future<List<Opciones>> listOpciones = DatabaseHelper.instance.verOpciones();
    //print((listOpciones));
    return listOpciones[0];
  }

Comment: Ese es otro issue, podrías registrarlo en otra pregunta dando datos más claros.